# Assign image source in code-behind of XAML control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following xaml

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelBanner" Grid.Row="1"></StackPanel>
```

I had to write this much messy code to add picture to it.

```
var toplogoBitmap = new BitmapImage();
toplogoBitmap.BeginInit();
toplogoBitmap.UriSource = new Uri(@"" + _appPath + "images/toplogo.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
toplogoBitmap.EndInit();

var toplogoImage = new Image
{
    Source = toplogoBitmap,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    Stretch = Stretch.None
};
StackPanelBanner.Children.Add(toplogoImage);
```

Because i have to get the images from folder, which will be changing on time to time, i can't put them in resources.

Is there any short way of adding picture in XAML control. i.e

```
<StackPanel source="toplogo" x:Name="StackPanelBanner" Grid.Row="1"></StackPanel>
```

in Codebehind

```
var toplogo = @"" + _appPath + "images/toplogo.png";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "messy" code is pretty much the code you would need to add an item to a content control.  You can't really shorten it, but if you're doing this regularly, refactoring to a method could help reduce the extra code required:

```
public void AddImageToContainer(string path, Panel parent)
{
    var bmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(_appPath + path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    var img = new Image
    {
        Source = bmap,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
        Stretch = Stretch.None
    };
    parent.Children.Add(img);
}
```

You could then just call this as needed, ie:

```
AddImageToContainer("images/toplogo.png", StackPanelBanner);
```

Comment: There is no need for the BeginInit/EndInit calls as long as you don't want to set any other BitmapImage properties than the UriSource. You may shorten it to `var bmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(_appPath + path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));`.

Comment: @ReedCopsey this is lovely, noobish i am, never thought of that. will the same function work for Grid, or `Panel` parameter is just for `StackPanel`

Comment: @ADi Panel will work for any Panel derivitive - including Grid.

Comment: Thanks all for ur time, and the answe also gave me new ideas to experiment with. And @Clemens thanks for shorting even more of my messy code :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `ItemsControl` that uses a `StackPanel` as its `ItemsPanel`.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" Grid.Row="1">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

You might now add images as easy as shown below, because WPF provides built-in type conversion from `string` (or `Uri`) to `ImageSource`:

```
itemsControl.Items.Add(_appPath + "images/toplogo.png");
```

Comment: Given that it's a StackPanel, I'm guessing the OP wants to add multiple images to the container (otherwise, a different container would make more sense...)

Comment: As a logical next step you would data-bind the ItemsControl's ItemsSource property to an ObservableCollection of image path strings in your view model.